# Evaluating limits: $\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^3}$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-} -\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^3}$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-} -\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^3}$

Is there any way to calculate this limits in a "formal" way, or should I just plug in very little values around 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plugging very little values around $0$ will tell you how it behaves and you can find the limit this way. This method works here because you have a limit which is quite easy to evaluate.

Comment: Usually when it's 1-sided limits, your best guess is to plug in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of calculating these limits formally, however, you can also use mathematical reasoning. [The right hand limit is $-\infty$, and the left-hand limit is $+\infty$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+to+0+of+-%28%28x-1%29%5E2%29%2Fx%5E3). Notice that as $x$ becomes smaller, $f(x):=-\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{x^3}$ grows smaller and smaller, as near $0$, $(x-1)^2>x^3$. A similar reasoning can be applied to the left-hand limit, to see that near $0$, $(x-1)^2<x^3$, thus forcing the right hand limit to be $-\infty$, and the left-hand limit to be $+\infty$.